# Can I specify solution or search space in Z3?

Tags: z3

Let me explain my question with an example:

Suppose, I have a domain of possible discrete integers, e.g., -1, 0, 2, 3, 5 and 6
Now, I am looking for a solution (or model) for a variable x that will satisfy the following constraints:

(x > 0) && (x < 6) && (x != 3) && (x > 2)

The answer will be (from the solution domain) = 5, right?

How can I do this in Z3?

That is, I would like to define solution space using discrete entities and then assert few constraints and ask Z3 to check for satisfiablity. If satisfyable, then want the model.

Can anyone help me with the example?

Thank you,
--Ishtiaque

Answer (score 2):

Asserting that `x == -1 || x == 0 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 6` as an axiom beforehand should do it. I don't know if Z3 has a better way built into it though.

Edit:
Another solution may be to use an array, though I haven't used them before. Conceptually it should be possible to declare an array `A` that contains the numbers, and then say:

(exists (y Int) (=(select A y) x))`

Not sure if that is the exact syntax as I haven't used arrays before, but hopefully it should work.